# Is it possible to add custom claims through CLI?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

Our Application will have a limited amount of admin users that I would like to manually add an admin custom claims to their account. As such I would like to be able to just manually add a custom claims directly through the firebase console or CLI locally on my machine. This action might occur once a year only or not at all for just one user. If it cannot be done through the CLI is there another way to do it on my machine locally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no command in the CLI to add custom claims.

The simplest way I've found to add custom claims is through a tiny node.js script, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk):

> ```
> admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})
> ```